# How do you connect an Azure Function (not an App Service) to an on-premise SQL server via a VPN?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-vpn

I have a large SQL server hosted in our infrastructure, and an Azure resource set up with VPN access to our servers.

I want to create an Azure Function that connects to this SQL server. It's going to be a webhook endpoint to save to that DB. I don't need the overhead of an App Service Plan, I want the lightweight Function and the cheaper consumption pricing model.

All the tutorials online refer to App Services and Hybrid Connections that don't appear to be available in to Azure Functions on Consumption Plans.

I also want to keep the connection string configuration in Azure, and not hard-coded in the source or publish (which will ultimately be via CI).

The Azure Function is currently coded in C# in VS2019, but I can change that if it helps.

How do I set this up?

Comment: Have you explore this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/05/16/how-to-azure-function-app-with-hybrid-connection/
https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/13/azure-functions-azure-functions-using-hybrid-connections/

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT Yes, and if you read those blogs the first thing both state is switch to the more expensive App Service Plan. I'm asking whether this can be done on a Consumption Plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available on consumption plan. There is a already user voice open for this.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/33398398-add-support-for-hybrid-connections-to-consumption

[image]

Comment: Cheers, we came to the same conclusion about this today too - it's Microsoft's awful and deliberately obtuse licensing (again). _Consumption Plans_ block all virtual networking because money. A new feature called _Premium Plans_ are in beta and offer increased usage costing without the full App Service overhead, and these do allow VPN connections.

Comment: I realise this is a slightly different question but does Azure function consumption plan support connection to Azure SQL server hosted fully in Azure. (the PaaS Azure SQL server). Are there issues regarding whitelisting of IP address or is that covered if you use managed identity ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You would need to use something like Hybrid Connection. Does not matter which IDE you used to create the function.Check out the following link.

> The Hybrid Connections feature requires a relay agent in the network
>   that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint. That relay agent is called
>   the Hybrid Connection Manager (HCM). To download HCM, from your app in
>   the Azure portal, select Networking > Configure your Hybrid Connection
>   endpoints.

[`Azure App Service Hybrid Connections`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks, but I do state in the question that Hybrid Connections are not available without upgrading to a more expensive pricing structure. I'm asking whether this can be done without that.